# SQUID Monitoring tool

Tags: squid

I have install "Squid for windows" server on my network to provide shared Internet access to about 6 users and it is work fine.

My main purpose to setup squid is save bans width of my 4G Internet connection, but I do not find any traffic monitoring tool, to monitor users activity, hit rate and miss rate of server.

I want to know what are the available GUI monitoring tool for Squid and how to configure in windows environment?

Answer (score 0):

squid cache manager tool will give you information about request rates, failure, CPU and memory utilization and such details. I'm not sure whether it give user-wise/ip-wise details of requests.

If you are using any authentication in proxy, you can log username against each log entry, write an app to process your squid access log so that you can get all details against ip/username

Answer (score 0):

You can use squid analysis and report generator which will give you all required information.